# How to prove that there is a $C$ such that $|f(\eta)-f(y)|\le C|\eta-y|f'(\eta)$

Tags: analysis

> Let $$\Omega=\{\phi\in C^{1}[-1,1]\colon\phi{(-1)}<\phi{(1)},|\phi'|\le 1\}.$$
>
> Prove that
>
> there exists a constant $C$, such that $\forall f\in \Omega$ there $\exists\eta\in[-1,1]$, such that $f'(\eta)>0$ and
> $$ |f(\eta)-f(y)|\le C|\eta-y|f'(\eta),\forall y\in [-1,1]. $$

This question comes from a problem book in analysis by Min HUI Xie, with the suggestion to argue by contradiction as its only hint.

Comment: Check the mean value theorem.

Comment: A minor observation: We can take $C=1$ on the subset of $\Omega$ consisting of those functions $\phi$ such that $\max \phi'=\max|\phi'|$: Simply take $\eta$ such that $\phi'(\eta)$ is largest, and use the mean value theorem.